# Tangent Space to Fiber Product of Transverse Mappings

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm trying to show two things: that for two smooth transverse mappings $f:X \to Z$ and $g:Y \to Z$, the map $h:W \to Z\times Z$, $h'(x,y)(v_x,v_y) = (f'(x)(v_x), g'(y)(v_y))$ is surjective (I see that it happens to be the case that this is true for vector spaces, but I'm frustrated that I can't prove it in general), and the tangent space $T_{(x,y)}W$ where $W$ consists of $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ such that $f(x) = g(y)$ is contained in the kernel of the map $\phi:T_xX \times T_yY \to T_zZ$ defined by $\phi(v_x,v_y) = f'(x)(v_x) - g'(y)(v_y)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One idea is that $(f'(x)(T_xX), g'(y)(T_yY)$ is equal to $f'(x)(T_xX) \oplus g'(y)(T_yY)$ which by transversality of the mappings spans all of $T_{f(x)}Z$, but the mapping $h'$ is defined from $T_xX \times T_yY \to T_zZ \times T_zZ$, so this doesn't seem to make sense for $T_zZ \times T_zZ$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you expect people here to help you prove some map is surjective, the least you can do is specify its domain and codomain.

Comment: As you write in your comment, this map is not surjective. Why not take instead $(x,y)(v_x,v_y)\mapsto f'(x)(v_x)+g'(y)(v_y)$. This is onto $T_zZ$.

Comment: @user1447447, "clear from context" is not a good answer to someone who does not understand what you are asking and *still* has the goodwill to help you. The fact that what you seemed to think to be "clear from context" is apparently wrong does not really help...

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I need to show that the differential of $h$ is surjective in order to show that $W$ is an embedded submanifold.

Comment: If you think that a comment is harsh, then the very last thing you ought to to is to respond harshly. And no, the differential of your h is not surjective: count dimensions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez $T_zZ \times T_zZ$ has dimension equal to the dimension of $T_zZ$ - the tangent space to the diagonal is equal to the diagonal of the tangent space.

Comment: @user1447447 For any non-trivial vector space $V$, you have $\dim V\times V>\dim V$.

Comment: Well, I am a moderator on this site, so one of the things I am supposed to do here is that...

Comment: @AmitaiYuval $T_{(z,z)}Z\times Z$ is equal to the diagonal of the tangent space $T_zZ \times T_zZ$. This would seem to me to have dimension equal to the dimension of $T_zZ$. That is, it's not simply the cross-product of two vector spaces.

Comment: You probably want that notation to mean that but it doesn't.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez feel free to correct.

Comment: So many comments were written here after the answer had already been given. In fact, you answered yourself in the first (!) comment: the differential of the map you describe is *not* onto. So this is not the way to prove the theorem about smoothness of the fiber product. You need to define a different map for that.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval - I'm not trying to prove anything related to the smoothness of the fiber product. I'm trying to prove that $W$, the domain of $h$, is a smooth embedded submanifold. I might need to give an extra step to formally show that $h'$ is onto $T_{(z,z)}Z \times Z$, but I'm fairly sure that the map is in fact onto, as tangent space of the diagonal is the diagonal of the tangent space $T_zZ \times T_zZ$, and therefore has the same dimension as $T_zZ$. Please give an argument as to why the map is not onto.

Comment: @user1447447 Both Mariano and myself explained quite a few times why it is not surjective in general. And by the way, the space $W=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y|f(x)=g(y)\}$ is called the fiber product. So, either you are trying to prove smoothness of the fiber product, or your question is even less clear than what I thought it was to begin with.

Comment: And if you want to prove $W$ is smooth, I'll be actually happy to help. But as for now, I don't really understand what you're after.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I called that space the fiber product in my question to begin with. Is smoothness of the fiber product was equivalent to an embedding or a submersion... You both said that the map wasn't surjective because of dimension-counting, but never responded to the fact that the image has the same dimension as $T_zZ$.

Comment: Yes, that would be great if you could help me to show that $W$ is an embedded submanifold of $X \times Y$.

Comment: (accidentally deleted comment) It might be possible to define a map from $W→\mathbb{R}^k$ where $k$ is the dimension of $Z$, such that $h(x,y)=\phi(f(x)) - \phi(g(y))$, where $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism from $U⊂Z→\mathbb{R}^k$, which would clearly have a surjective differential, but I'm not sure how to make this more formal, it only works locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea in your last comment works indeed. And local is enough, as being an embedded submanifold is a local property. That is, it is enough to show that for any $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ with $f(x)=g(y)$, there is an open neighborhood $(x,y)\in U\subset X\times Y$ such that $W\cap U$ is an embedded submanifold of $U$.

Now, suppose $f(x_0)=g(y_0)=z_0$, and let $(V,\phi)$ be a coordinate chart of $Z$ around $z_0$. Write $U:=f^{-1}(V)\times g^{-1}(V)\subset X\times Y$, and define$$k:U\to\mathbb{R}^k,\quad (x,y)\mapsto \phi(f(x))-\phi(g(y)).$$ By construction, we have $W\cap U=k^{-1}(0).$ It follows from transversality that $0$ is a regular value of $k$, and the claim follows from the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this does indeed make sense, I have just been operating on bad advice from another question on here, and was convinced that $h'$ was a surjective map.